# how do I get my buttons to move down in my website?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to get my website to be mobile friendly. Whenever it gets to 700 max width I have my buttons stacked on top of each other but I don't know how to get them to move down the screen! Most sites I looked on say to either use position absolute then do left whatever px or % and The other people say to use margin but that doesn't work because if I do top-margin it spaces out all the other buttons! any ideas? I hope I explained it well.

```
<head>
<title>MorganaWhite|About Me</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5e/Metro-M.svg/2000px-Metro-M.svg.png">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="about.css">
<style>
body {
    background-color: #e3e3e3;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Arial;
}
.header {
    background: url(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-lYQ3vQHE3Mo/VrVKGwg8pqI/AAAAAAAADMQ/QKjs5ALViKo/w530-d-h253-p-rw/desk%2Bbackground.png) no-repeat left fixed; 
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    text-align: center;
    height: 700px;
    }

.mobilelinks {display: none;}

.wrapper {
    margin: 50px;
}

#footer {
    text-align: center;
}

#footer a {
    color: #666;
    margin-left: 8px;
}

#footer a:hover {
    color: #222;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

h1 {
    color: white;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 72px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
h2 {
    color: #525252;
    font-size: 36px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-align: center;

}
p {
    font-family: Gill Sans, sans-serif;
    color:#696969;
    font-size: 17px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 150%;
}
a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration:none;
}

ul li {
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    background-color: rgba(5, 4, 2, 0.1);
    border: 2px solid white;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 90%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 40px;
        margin-left: 11%;
        margin-top: 12%;
}

ul li:hover {
    background-color: white;
}
ul li:hover > a {
    color: #000;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {
    .header {height: 300px;}
        ul li {margin-top: 0%;}
    ul li { }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    h1 {
        font-size: 52px;
    }
    ul li {margin-top: 0%;}
        .links {display: none;}
    .mobilelinks {display: inline-block;}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {
    .header {height: 300px;}
    ul li {margin-top: 0%;}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    h1 {
        font-size: 52px;
    }
    .links {display: none;}
    ul li {margin-top: 0%;}
    .mobilelinks {display: inline-block;}
}


  @media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    .header {height: 200px;}
    .mobile-terms { display: none;}
    h1 {
        font-size: 36px;
    }
    h2 {
        font-size: 22px;
    }
    ul li {margin-top: 0%;}
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <h1>WHO I AM</h1>
                  <ul class="links">
                     <li><a href="www.youtube.com"><strong>MY LIFE</strong></a></li>
                     <li><a href="www.youtube.com"><strong>PORTFOLIO</strong></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#middle"><strong>RESUME</strong></a></li>
                     <li><a href="about.html"><strong>ABOUT ME</strong></a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="mobilelinks">
                <li><a href="www.youtube.com"><strong>MY LIFE</strong></a></li>
                <li><a href="www.youtube.com"><strong>PORTFOLIO</strong></a></li>
                <li><a href="#middle"><strong>RESUME</strong></a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html"><strong>ABOUT ME</strong></a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="mainwrapper">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <h2>Some Fun Facts</h2>
                <p>
                I made this website from scratch when I was 14, <br>
                I have a twin brother whose name is Pierson McNeal White, <br>
                I have a older brother and sister who are also twins, <br>
                I used to have 2 pet rats named Hermes and Cleo after the greek gods, <br>
                and I watch the super bowl for the ads.
                </p>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <h2>Me In A Nutshell</h2>
                <p>
                Other Crap Here.
                </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
            Copyright &copy;&nbsp;<script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear())</script>&nbsp;Morgan.
          <div>
            <a href="#">Link</a>
            <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
            <a href="#">Terms<span class="mobile-terms"> of Service</span></a>
          </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason here is the **`height`** you gave to your **`.header`** i.e. **`300px`**. Change it to some enough pixels so that your buttons could get enough sapce to tuck in.

I **would suggest better using** **`auto`** or **`100vh`**, but than it's your **wish**.

**[Working : Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/divy3993/n1ufdnqp/)**

```css
body {
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.header {
  background: url(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-lYQ3vQHE3Mo/VrVKGwg8pqI/AAAAAAAADMQ/QKjs5ALViKo/w530-d-h253-p-rw/desk%2Bbackground.png) no-repeat left fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  height: 700px;
}

.mobilelinks {
  display: none;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 50px;
}

#footer {
  text-align: center;
}

#footer a {
  color: #666;
  margin-left: 8px;
}

#footer a:hover {
  color: #222;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 72px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

h2 {
  color: #525252;
  font-size: 36px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  font-family: Gill Sans, sans-serif;
  color: #696969;
  font-size: 17px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 150%;
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul li {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  background-color: rgba(5, 4, 2, 0.1);
  border: 2px solid white;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 90%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-left: 11%;
  margin-top: 12%;
}

ul li:hover {
  background-color: white;
}

ul li:hover > a {
  color: #000;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {
  .header {
    height: 100vh; /* OR USE AUTO */
    
  }
  ul li {
    margin-top: 0%;
  }
  ul li {}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 52px;
  }
  ul li {
    margin-top: 0%;
  }
  .links {
    display: none;
  }
  .mobilelinks {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .header {
    height: 100vh; /* OR USE AUTO */
  }
  ul li {
    margin-top: 0%;
  }
  .mobile-terms {
    display: none;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 36px;
  }
  h2 {
    font-size: 22px;
  }
}

color: #000;

}
@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {
  .header {
    height: 100vh; /* OR USE AUTO */
  }
  
  ul li {
    margin-top: 0%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 52px;
  }
  
  .links {
    display: none;
  }
  
  ul li {
    margin-top: 0%;
  }
  
  .mobilelinks {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .header {
    height: 100vh; /* OR USE AUTO */
  }
  
  .mobile-terms {
    display: none;
  }
  
  h1 {
    font-size: 36px;
  }
  
  h2 {
    font-size: 22px;
  }
  
  ul li {
    margin-top: 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>WHO I AM</h1>
  <ul class="links">
    <li><a href="www.youtube.com"><strong>MY LIFE</strong></a></li>
    <li><a href="www.youtube.com"><strong>PORTFOLIO</strong></a></li>
    <li><a href="#middle"><strong>RESUME</strong></a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html"><strong>ABOUT ME</strong></a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="mobilelinks">
    <li><a href="www.youtube.com"><strong>MY LIFE</strong></a></li>
    <li><a href="www.youtube.com"><strong>PORTFOLIO</strong></a></li>
    <li><a href="#middle"><strong>RESUME</strong></a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html"><strong>ABOUT ME</strong></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="mainwrapper">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h2>Some Fun Facts</h2>
    <p>
      I made this website from scratch when I was 14,
      <br> I have a twin brother whose name is Pierson McNeal White,
      <br> I have a older brother and sister who are also twins,
      <br> I used to have 2 pet rats named Hermes and Cleo after the greek gods,
      <br> and I watch the super bowl for the ads.
    </p>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h2>Me In A Nutshell</h2>
    <p>
      Other Crap Here.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
  Copyright &copy;&nbsp;
  <script>
    document.write(new Date().getFullYear())

  </script>&nbsp;Morgan.
  <div>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
    <a href="#">Terms<span class="mobile-terms"> of Service</span></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="header">
  <h1>WHO I AM</h1>
  <ul class="links">
    <li><a href="www.youtube.com"><strong>MY LIFE</strong></a></li>
    <li><a href="www.youtube.com"><strong>PORTFOLIO</strong></a></li>
    <li><a href="#middle"><strong>RESUME</strong></a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html"><strong>ABOUT ME</strong></a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="mobilelinks">
    <li><a href="www.youtube.com"><strong>MY LIFE</strong></a></li>
    <li><a href="www.youtube.com"><strong>PORTFOLIO</strong></a></li>
    <li><a href="#middle"><strong>RESUME</strong></a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html"><strong>ABOUT ME</strong></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="mainwrapper">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h2>Some Fun Facts</h2>
    <p>
      I made this website from scratch when I was 14,
      <br> I have a twin brother whose name is Pierson McNeal White,
      <br> I have a older brother and sister who are also twins,
      <br> I used to have 2 pet rats named Hermes and Cleo after the greek gods,
      <br> and I watch the super bowl for the ads.
    </p>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h2>Me In A Nutshell</h2>
    <p>
      Other Crap Here.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
  Copyright &copy;&nbsp;
  <script>
    document.write(new Date().getFullYear())

  </script>&nbsp;Morgan.
  <div>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
    <a href="#">Terms<span class="mobile-terms"> of Service</span></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just as i said. Change your `height` for **`.header`**. Check the height in all `@media screen` for  **`.header`**.

Comment: and that's all you did? is there a way to just move to buttons up some?

Comment: Yes, that's just what i did.

Comment: Yes, you can move them up by reducing your **`margin-top:12%`** inside `ul li` of your CSS.

Comment: what about only when its small?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103145/discussion-between-morgan-and-divy3993).

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is a bit messed up, please clean it up. E.g. you have `@media screen and (max-width: 400px)` twice. And you do not need to duplicate the ul to make it the mobile style.

Comment: oh ok let me do that